# How to autofilter, offset, and copy values to new sheet Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Salutations bretheren! My name is Christopher.

Lately I've been racing through a stream of excel projects and I think I've overheated my brain. If you guys could bring me some cool water, it'd be much appreciated!

So I have a sheet which I was using as an inventory sheet, and it is non-interactive and dated. Not to mention I was storing inventory information for each part in multiple rows (graphically nice, not very functional.)

I've made a new (better) workbook already, so now I just want to take some of my old data and copy it to a new sheet (in the old workbook) that fits my new single-row format. I will be straight copying and pasting the information from that sheet into my new-and-improved workbook

I have some code which I will post at the end, and what I am trying to make it do is this:

In my Sheet1, I want AutoFilter to find the first text value "LOC" in column A, then offset to column B to get my part's location. Then it will offset one row down to get the part number. After that it will offset another two rows down to get the description.

In my Sheet2, I want to find the first empty row. Then I want the information I found in Sheet1 to be deposited into columns A, B, and C of that empty row.

I hope I have been quite specific, to the point and to a better effect not silly in the way I am asking for assistance!

Here I will post my code, and I am thankful for any and all recommendations, code tweaks, and help!

Thank you!

-Christopher

P.S. Beware, as you may laugh. My coding has been known to be laughable at times. I ALWAYS appreciate explanations of why something works, doesn't work, or why another thing that works would be better in a given circumstance!

Code:

```
    Sub CopyStuff()

    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Loc
    Dim Part
    Dim Desc

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

    With Sheets("Sheet2")

        Set Part = iRow.Offset(0, 0)
        Set Loc = iRow.Offset(0, 1)
        Set Desc = iRow.Offset(0, 2)

    End With

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .AutoFilter 1, "LOC"
        .Offset(0, 1).Copy Loc
        .Offset(1, 0).Copy Part
        .Offset(2, 0).Copy Desc
        .AutoFilter
    End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: Although your find last row works, I like the shorter version, and it is easy to memorize`iRow=ws.cells(ws.rows.count,"A").end(xlup).row` +1 if you want to make it 1 row past

Comment: Thank you for that helpful hint Dave!
I am going to start using that instead, it seems much more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my Sheet1, I want AutoFilter to find the first text value "LOC" in column A, then offset to column B to get my part's location. Then it will offset one row down to get the part number.

You don't need Autofilter for this since you have to retrieve the value from multiple rows. Use `.Find` instead

```
Sub CopyStuff()
    Dim wsIRow As Long, wsORow As Long
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range

    Set wsI = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsO = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    wsORow = wsO.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
             SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

    With wsI
        wsIRow = wsI.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
                 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row

        Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & wsIRow)

        With rng
            Set aCell = .Find(What:="LOC", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                wsO.Range("A" & wsORow).Value = aCell.Value
                wsO.Range("B" & wsORow).Value = aCell.Offset(, 1).Value
                wsO.Range("C" & wsORow).Value = aCell.Offset(1, 1).Value
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Let's say `Sheet1` looks like this

[image]

The output then will look like this

[image]

Comment: You got it exactly as I was imagining it! Now as a sidenote, how would I make it continue doing its work? It seems to only copy the first entry in my original Sheet1.

Comment: [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) will get you started ;) See how you can use `.FindNext`

Comment: Thank you guys a lot, this has made my day way easier and better! 
Have a great one!